# Область видимости переменных андроид студио

Tags: java, android-studio, videoview

Дан код:

```
public interface Api {
    @GET("place/all/{id}")
    Call<List<Model>> galleryContent(@Path("id") int result);
}

public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.osh.digital/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
       if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}

public class Model {
    public String video;
    public String getVideo() {
        return video;
    }
}

public class QRActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String urlVideo;
    TextView textView;
    VideoView videoView;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr);
        loadData();
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        setupVideoView(videoView,  urlVideo);
        //setupVideoView(videoView, "http://api.osh.digital/media/02.mp4");
    }

    private void setupVideoView(VideoView videoView, String url){
        videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
        videoView.start();
        textView.append(" " + url);
    }

    public void loadData() {
        Api api = ApiClient.getClient().create(Api.class);
        Call<List<Model>> gallery = api.galleryContent(0);
        gallery.enqueue(new Callback<List<Model>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Model>> call, Response<List<Model>> response) {
            if (response.body() != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i("test", "onResponse: " + response.body().size());
            } else {
                try {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.errorBody().string());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            List<Model> models = response.body();
            Model model = models.get(0);
            urlVideo = model.getVideo();
            //textView.append(urlVideo);
        }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Model>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("tes2", "onFailure: " + t);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что при запуске приложение вылетает, показывая при этом в логкате:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:490)
    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:480)
    at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:452)
    at com.example.b.QR.QRActivity.setupVideoView(QRActivity.java:50)
    at com.example.b.QR.QRActivity.onCreate(QRActivity.java:40)
```

Comment: в onCreate вы вызываете setupVideoView и передаете ему строку urlVideo. Вы просто её (urlVideo) объявили, но ничего в нее не "положили". Вот "ничего" и передаете

Comment: как передать ей не пустой линк?

Comment: пардон. в loadData вы присваете urlVideo = model.getVideo(); тут смотрите что присваиваете

Comment: не могу из urlVideo в loadData() положить в urlVideo в setupVideoView()...

Comment: private String urlVideo; private попробуйте убрать отсюда

Comment: не вариант, к сожалению

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92690/discussion-between-ilim-sarykbaev-and-timurvi).

Comment: Дело в том, что у вас асинхронный сетевой запрос, на связь и получение ответа уходит намного больше времени, чем выполняется код в onCreate(), когда вы пытаетесь использовать значение ссылки, оно еще не "пришло" из интернета.  `setupVideoView()` нужно вызывать после того, как запрос получен и обработан - в методе onResponse() (и код по заполнению model из полученого ответа сервера нужно перенсти туда же)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class QRActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;
VideoView videoView;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr);
    loadData();
    textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
}

public void loadData() {
    final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    Api api = ApiClient.getClient().create(Api.class);
    Call<List<Model>> gallery = api.galleryContent(0);
    gallery.enqueue(new Callback<List<Model>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Model>> call, Response<List<Model>> response) {
            if (response.body() != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i("test", "onResponse: " + response.body().size());
                textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                List<Model> models = response.body();
                Model model = models.get(1);
                String urlVideo = model.getVideo();
                videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);

                mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlVideo));
                videoView.start();
                textView.append(" " + urlVideo);
            } else {
                try {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.errorBody().string());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Model>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("tes2", "onFailure: " + t);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: ссылку на textView вы получаете после вызова метода loadData() где она используется, а это опять NPE. Надо перенести до вызова метода. Так же туда же нужно перенести получение ссылки на videoView, такие вещи получают один раз в onCreate(), а не при каждом обращении к виджету